# Specific Lookup Formula

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, formula, vlookup, spreadsheet

I'm trying to search through an entire column of text (B3 downwards), and finding any matches in the column (S3 downwards) and if so grab the cells from columns T through to X and paste them into the correct match's row in the columns I to M.

I believe I need to do something with INDEX and MATCH but my excel skills aren't great!

[image]

I've attached an example picture here to explain, so Im searching through the column on the left through the column on the right, and if it's matching grabbing the information highlighted yellow and adding it to the blank cells highlighted yellow, then the next match is the pink highlighted numbers and thats added into the second row inline with the corresponding name! Hope this makes sense!

Comment: Check Function [VLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1). It does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your poorly cropped image...

use in row 3:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B3:B; S:X; {2\3\4\5\6}; 0)))
```

or for english based sheets:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B3:B, S:X, {2,3,4,5,6}, 0)))
```

Comment: That's it thank you very much!